# Windows Phone 8.1 - FileOpenPicker filter by name

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone app (Windows Runtime, not Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1). In it, I have to let the user select multiple photos to do some processing with them. To accomplish this, I'm using the FileOpenPicker class, and it works fine. But I want to show only the pictures whose name doesn't start with a given string, for example, "abc-". So, in this case, I would only want the FileOpenPicker to display the pictures whose name doesn't start with " abc-".
So, is it possible to do this? If it is not possible, how can I accomplish it?
 Thank you.
(I'm launching the FileOpenPicker with

```
fileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can filter only on the file type.

You can post or vote for feature requests on the [Windows Dev Platform Feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com).