# FileOpenPicker Filters

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, fileopenpicker

Is it possible to describe filters of FileOpenPicker?

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
```

In Windows Forms dialog boxes it was possible:

```
dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
```

Comment: Based on the [docs of FileOpenPicker class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker) as well as [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28098947/6741868), it seems you cannot filter names, only file types.